# EXTJS GridPanel Selection Model

Tags: extjs

I have a GridPanel, 
when i am binding the GridPanel from database, bydefault some rows should be selected.
how can i do this.
can u please help me.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
Ext.getCmp('grid').getSelectionModel().selectRow(RowIndex);
```

Comment: In Ext JS 4 there is no selectRow method.

Comment: @Justin : It works for ExtJS 3, &  OP has not mentioned the Ext Version then how can you say that its Ext 4?

Comment: Very true.  We don't really know what version... LOL - Now, 3.X people can use your answer and 4.X users can use mine.  As an aside, getCmp is still available in 4.X, but the developers advise against using it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('NameOfYourGridAlias');
grid[0].getSelectionModel().select(RowIndex);
```